# How can I always get Timestamp in certain format without having to explicitly define it everytime

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

When I run a select on a timestamp I get something like: `2015-01-02T23:22:36.000Z, 1/7/2015 11:03:31 AM`

In order to format properly I have to do:

```
SELECT to_char(entered, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
FROM analytics WHERE business_id = 371746;
```

or even worse:

```
var statement = "SELECT service_id, analytic_id, queues.business_id, name, queues.queue_id,";
    statement += "  to_char(serviced, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') as serviced,";
    statement += "  to_char(called, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') as called,";
    statement += "  to_char(entered, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') as entered ";
    statement += "  FROM queues INNER JOIN analytics";
    statement += "  ON queues.queue_id = analytics.queue_id";
    statement += "  AND queues.business_id = " + business_id + "";
    statement += "  AND line_id = " + line_id + " ORDER BY queues.queue_id";
```

which is kind of a pain, since I often just do `SELECT *` and don't specify the fields.

Is there a way to tell Postgres to always return this kind of format `'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'` from a SELECT without having to specify the to_char every time?

Comment: Formatting of `date` or `timestamp` columns is up to the SQL client you use. You need to check the manual of your SQL client if you can set a default format.

Comment: x-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88777/how-can-i-always-get-timestamp-in-certain-format-without-having-to-explicitly-de

Comment: Looks like this code is prone to SQL injection, string concatenation within a query isn't a good idea. Please check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thi is about as close as it gets.

```
var statement = "
    SET datestyle to SQL,MDY ;
    SET lc_time   to  'en_us.utf8' ;
    SELECT ...
```

except en_us  seems to be a 24 hour clock.

Comment: is this something you run once? or need to do it before every query? regards

Answer (score 3):

You could create a server-side view definition that does all the `to_char` conversions:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT
    to_char(serviced, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') as serviced,
      ....
      ....
```

Then from Javascript direct your query against the view instead of the concrete table (or surgically choose columns from the view or the table, depending on how you define the view).

Comment: the VIEW needs to have the entire SELECT statement or I can just reference the 'view_name' within any SELECT statement?  regards

Comment: In the client-side query you can treat the view as a distinct table.  So as long as there is some way to correlate the rows in the view to the rows in the real table (from your query it looks like you could include `queue_id` in the view to permit this), you can include the view in the join and reference those particular columns.

Comment: @user2040670: Then you might want to accept *this* answer.